# How to set all post data in ModelMap in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have many input fields in a form to post data to server side.
And in controller, I want to get all attributes in ModelMap like this:

```
public String save(ModelMap model) {
    ....
}
```

I don't want to use @RequestParam since there are so many fields to be sent. I think the data in a form will be posted and saved in ModelMap automatically, but its not working

Could anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a @ModelAttribute in the form handler

```
@RequestMapping(value="/submitform", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute("mydata") MyData myData) {

 //do something with
 //myData.getField1();
 //myData.getFiled2();
}
```

and this is how you will send the page to the form

```
@RequestMapping("/fillform")
public String loadForm(ModelMap model) {

  //you could also fill MyData, to do autofill on the html form
  model.put("mydata", new MyData());

  return "fillform"; //[jsp]view resolver will pick up fillform.jsp 
 }
```

Comment: so you mean, I can only get data in <form> with @ModelAttribute("mydata"), these data will not be saved into ModelMap automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to make the same thing. The problem with previous answer is taht the UI is dynamically build by iterating on `Map<String, Object>`. 
So it is not possible to pre define the MyData.class.

I am solving this issue using next approach:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/secure/filled", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveFilledData(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
request.getParameter("nameOfTheParameter");
}`